# set Element attributes by CSS property, is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml, properties

the css code

```
input.long{
    width:50%;
    max-length:50;
}
input.number{
    width:4em;
    max-length:4;
}
```

to apply html code,

```
Title : <input type='text' class='long'/>
Phone : <input type='text' class='short'/>-<input type='text' class='short'/>-<input type='text' class='short'/>
```

a script(simply using jquery) to apply attribute in css,

```
$('input:text.long').attr('maxlength',$('input:text.long').css('max-length'));
$('input:text.short').attr('maxlength',$('input:text.short').css('max-length'));
```

work on IE but not work other browsers.
can I single or multiple setting element attribute by css property on major browsers?

Comment: set the max length on input type be default// why do you want to set at runtime

Comment: Why must you set this from CSS?

Comment: @josh , he gave that as css value and trying to ready that through .css//

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code most likely does not work because "max-length" is not a valid CSS attribute. My guess is jQuery returns `false` when you try to read a CSS property by that name. This `false` is then interpreted as `0` which is applied to the input's `maxlength`.

`maxlength` is a valid attribute for an `input`, and all it needs is an integer for a value. As long as you can get that from a CSS attribute, there's no reason it won't work. For example, if you take the computed CSS width instead and parse it as an integer, you can set the input's maxlength to that value. http://jsfiddle.net/sdq7H/

Comment: I see, but I saw this link (http://www.greytower.net/archive/articles/customcss.html) for trying my question.

Comment: I looked at the link. Maybe you meant to use `max-width`? There is no mention of "max-length" in that article.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is correct

max-length is wrong

```
$('input:text.long').css('max-length')
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to do this in CSS so that you can control the max length of all these textboxes from one spot?  Most server-side languages offer re-usable controls for this purpose.  CSS is the wrong tool for this job.  If you must do it on the client-side, what is the problem with just doing something like this...

```
$('input:text.long').attr('maxlength', 50);
$('input:text.short').attr('maxlength', 4);
```